# Make a `<table>` width equal to its children `<td>`

Tags: html, css, tablelayout, html-table

I have a `<table>` that I would like to have a width that contains its children `<td>`.

Unfortunately, I can only assign classes to the `<td>` columns, and not the `<th>` columns - so I can't use `table-layout: fixed` as I usually would. w3 spec on table-layout: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout

Do you know how to make a `<table>` width equal to its children `<td>`?

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                First
            </th>
            <th>
                Last
            </th>
            <th>
                Info
            </th>
            <th>
                Join Date
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">
                Don
            </td>
            <td class="last">
                P
            </td>
            <td class="info">
                Here is some rando info that can vary in length. I talk a lot.
            </td>
            <td class="join-date">
                2013-03-01
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">
                Tom
            </td>
            <td class="last">
                Smith
            </td>
            <td class="info">
                I'm a quiet person.
            </td>
            <td class="join-date">
                2013-04-22
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.first, .last, .join-date {
    width: 250px;
}

.info {
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 200%; /* so this column will expand */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content is fixed, assign manual width to the  of just the 1st .
The table will then adjust according to the width that you specify.

Eg :

```
 <table>
      <tr>
         <td style="width:100px"></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```